# Meaning of 尻を持ち込む

Tags: definitions

In the 4th sentence of the 3rd paragraph of [坊ちゃん](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000148/files/752_14964.html) is:

> 古川の持っている田圃の井戸を埋めて尻を持ち込まれた事もある。

I am not sure what is meant by 尻を持ち込まれた.

[According to Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%B0%BB%E3%82%92%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A1%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80) it means:

> 問題の後始末を他の人に頼む。

I take it to mean that 古川 asked someone (not the narrator) to empty out the well which the narrator filled. Would this be accurate? For some reason it seems a bit odd.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

明鏡国語辞典 says:

> 尻を持ち込む -- 後始末をつけるよう関係者に迫る。

So... here in your example I think it's closer to 後始末をつけるよう**[迫]{せま}る** "demand, press", than ～頼む "ask".

> 古川の持っている田圃の井戸を埋めて尻を持ち込まれた事もある。

古川 demanded the narrator (or probably his family) to empty out the well which he filled.

Comment: Wow what a difference in definitions! Thank you!